# Does GNU binutils have an machine instruction library?

Tags: assembly, disassembly

I am looking for programmatic ways to manipulate machine code, tasks like assembling and dissassembling.

GNU's `as` and `objdump` are very useful tools, but unfortunately I cannot find a library which would allow me to do this in code.

Is there such a library available or will I have to go digging in the binutils source?

**ETA:** What I want to do is basically build my own assembler. I am working on implementing my own assembler, and to code all the instruction codes by hand is tedius and error prone.

It is for learning, not production, and for some projects involving non-standard calling conventions.

Comment: allow you to do what in code?  manipulate machine code?  fopen(), fread(), fwrite(), fclose() is all you need.

Comment: LLVM was designed to be built into a library and manipulate machine code... http://llvm.org/, you can learn about the disassembler here http://blog.llvm.org/2010/01/x86-disassembler.html

Comment: ETA to address the concerns raised in the two previous comments.

Comment: Take a look at libopcodes and libbfd that GNU binutils use. Might be what you need. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132006

Comment: tedious and error prone yes, but that is the nature of the beast for assemblers.  there are many open source assemblers out there not just gas, that you can examine to see how folks have minimized the error.  I find the easiest way is to separately develop (dont share code, no cutting and pasting) an assembler and disassembler, such that the disassembler generates code that can be re-assembled.  if you take some code, assemble it, disassemble it and reassemble that and the two binaries match it helps to reduce the human error. not perfect but helps.

Comment: @dwelch That seems reasonable. I looked over a PowerPC assembler written in Haskell, and the author had coded every instruction by hand... I think I might do the same.