# Get function hex-codes from GCC

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

Now I encounter problem. My project works on assembly-level.
So I need assembly-level programming but the project scale is too large to do work on assembly-level only. Because of this issue, I determine get hexcodes from c-source-file made by gcc. but how? **How can I get certain function's *HEXCODES* by using gcc?**

I have a idea,

```
int function_name(){
    int a=1;
    return a;
}
write(fd, (char *)function_name, sizeof(function_name))
```

I would get hexcodes of *function_name* after this doing.
but It's not good way to solve this problem, It would make me need to handle many file when I need many function as target.

Is there other good way to solve this problem? I think ideal solution that need only function name(and output file name if needed) and works on command-line. Is ideal solution which I think impossible?

Also I assume that compiler's optimization options is off
so I would get **hexcodes** from *function_name* is *'\x55\x8B\xEC\x83\xEC\x04\xC7\x45\xFC\x01\x00\x00\x00\x8B\x45\xFC\x8B\xE5\x5D\xC3'*
*function_name*'s assembly code is below.

```
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP, ESP
SUB ESP, 4
MOV DWORD PTR[EBP-4], 1
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR[EBP-4]
MOV ESP, EBP
POP EBP
RETN
```

Comment: `gcc -S -o mycode.S mycode.c`. Add `-masm=intel` if you want readable output.

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh... I'm sorry... I have mistake on my questions. I mean assembly code as binary codes(opcodes)... Really sorry, Thanks to your answer

Comment: Why do you need to copy the binary output? If you want to select different functions depending on some conditions then function pointer is the way to go

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc My project is on assembly-programming-level. But only-assembly-level programming is too hard to handle BIG scale code. So I want to use trick, get assembly-code from gcc.

Comment: What you are asking is unclear. Please improve your question. Explain what you want to do and on which kind of files. Be specific, and give an example.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I edited my question a moment ago. sorry, and thank you

Comment: Define what is a function for you. I'm pretty sure you don't really know. (think about `static` functions, and about `inline`-d functions, assuming that the compiler is optimizing, e.g. `gcc -O2`)

Comment: I will vote for closing that question, or downvote it, since you don't explain enough what you are actually trying to do. Please **improve your question** *by editing it* (*not* by commenting it)!

Comment: Your example is precisely a function which would be inlined by most optimizing compilers. In such case, your question does not have any sense.

Comment: Then, you just need to understand the ELF format.

Comment: I voted to close your question. What you are asking is unclear, and shows that you did not enough research.

Comment: Maybe you want `objdump -d`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for your answer and really sorry about unclear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc produces an assembly file from every source file as part of the compilation toolchain. That file is usually temporary, and as such is immediately deleted. If you want it to be saved as `myfile.s`, you can use this command:

```
gcc -S -o myfile.s myfile.c
```

Comment: Oh... I'm sorry... I have mistake on my questions. I mean assembly code as binary codes(opcodes)... Really sorry, Thanks to your answer

Comment: @pyutic Your compiler already produces machine code. It's unclear what you mean by "get function assembly code". You can find the file offset start and end location with objdump or readelf of a function, and a view the executable/object file in a hex editor if you want - but perhaps that's not what you actually want

Comment: Actually, better try `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -S myfile.c`

Answer (score 1):

Try

objdump -D -Mintel yourfile.o

the dump will look like (.O generated by free pascal compiler, but gcc will be mostly the same)

```
   0:   55                      push   ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
   3:   8d 64 24 ec             lea    esp,[esp-0x14]
   7:   53                      push   ebx
   8:   89 45 fc                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],eax
   b:   c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x0
  12:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  14:   68 00 00 00 00          push   0x0
  19:   55                      push   ebp
  1a:   68 00 00 00 00          push   0x0
  1f:   64 ff 30                push   DWORD PTR fs:[eax]
  22:   64 89 20                mov    DWORD PTR fs:[eax],esp
  25:   c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0x0
  2c:   8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
  2f:   8b 50 04                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [eax+0x4]
```

The code is still relocatable, so references will be zero bytes.

To resolve that you need to objdump the binary (.exe) instead of the .o, but such output is usually huge, and will make finding a specific location harder.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are on Linux, since you are using `gcc`

You might run

```
 gcc -Wall -O -c myfile.c
```

to get an object file `myfile.o` from your source C file `myfile.c` ; that object file is in [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) so contains notably binary code and [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29) orders. You could parse that ELF object file (e.g. with commands like [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) or `readelf` or thru some library like `libelf` or `libbfd`)

Alternatively work only on ELF shared objects with [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) and use [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html). See [program library howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/)

Notice that not every source-level C function correspond to some function (e.g. ELF symbol) inside of object files (e.g. because of `static` functions - their name can be forgotten or [stripped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_%28Unix%29), or because of `inline` functions - they don't have their *own* machine code, it has been [inlined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) in the caller). Assume an [optimizing compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (e.g. `gcc -O2`).

Remember that [decompilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) is an impossible task in general. Be aware of the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) which is [undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem).

Look also at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9132006/841108) and the answers about `libopcode`

BTW,

```
write(fd, (char *)function_name, sizeof(function_name))
```

won't compile (you cannot take the `sizeof` some function). Maybe you would do

```
write(fd, (char*)function_name, sizeof(char*))
```

which will write some address, which might not mean much (be aware of [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)).

Maybe you want [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html)? You probably would need to compile your program with the `-rdynamic` option passed at linking time.

Comment: OP does not list a *nix or ELF as platform?