# Error compiling against libopcodes

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, binutils

I'm following some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132006/how-to-get-instruction-information-from-libopcodes) which is as follows:

The OP says that you can link with `-lbfd -lopcodes`.

However, for OpenSuSE I've found that for libbfd I need `-lbfd -liberty -lz -ldl`

When trying to compile, here is my results:

```
make

gcc ./main.c -lbfd -liberty -lz -ldl -lopcodes -g -o bfd_se

/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64/libopcodes.a(arm-dis.o): In function `print_insn_neon':
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/binutils-2.24/build-dir/opcodes/../../opcodes/arm-dis.c:2927: undefined reference to `floatformat_ieee_single_little'
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/binutils-2.24/build-dir/opcodes/../../opcodes/arm-dis.c:2927: undefined reference to `floatformat_to_double'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64/libopcodes.a(m68k-dis.o): In function `print_insn_arg':
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/binutils-2.24/build-dir/opcodes/../../opcodes/m68k-dis.c:1103: undefined reference to `floatformat_m68881_ext'
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/binutils-2.24/build-dir/opcodes/../../opcodes/m68k-dis.c:1103: undefined reference to `floatformat_to_double'
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/binutils-2.24/build-dir/opcodes/../../opcodes/m68k-dis.c:1099: undefined reference to `floatformat_ieee_double_big'
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/binutils-2.24/build-dir/opcodes/../../opcodes/m68k-dis.c:1099: undefined reference to `floatformat_to_double'
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/binutils-2.24/build-dir/opcodes/../../opcodes/m68k-dis.c:1095: undefined reference to `floatformat_ieee_single_big'
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/binutils-2.24/build-dir/opcodes/../../opcodes/m68k-dis.c:1095: undefined reference to `floatformat_to_double'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'bfd_se' failed
make: *** [bfd_se] Error 1
```

What other flags do I need to add to have this program compile? I see the error is related to different architectures, but I'm not trying to cross compile.

Thanks!

useful information:
uname -a

```
Linux node 4.0.5-THS_on #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jun 18 16:37:06 CDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

gcc --version

```
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.8.3 20140627 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 212064]
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

objdump --version (it uses libbfd and libopcodes)

```
GNU objdump (GNU Binutils; openSUSE 13.2) 2.24.0.20140403-6.1
Copyright 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) any later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time `libbfd` and `libopcodes` does not come as shared libraries in standard distributions (because they are not meant to be linked to). You must either link to the static libraries (`libbfd.a` and `libopcodes.a`) or recompile your distribution package and include the shared libraries in it (`.so` files).

So, to make it clear, try:

```
gcc ./main.c -liberty -lz -ldl -g -o bfd_se /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64/libopcodes.a /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64/libbfd.a
```

Comment: I have `binutils-dev` installed, but let me try that real quick

Comment: Doesn't work against the .a, but it does against the .so, and it is in the same directory as libbfd.so. Any ideas?

Comment: I meant, you should try to do the following: `gcc ./main.c  -liberty -lz -ldl -g -o bfd_se /usr/lib/libopcodes.a /usr/lib/libbdf.a` (or whatever is the path to both libraries).

Comment: The problem is, that wouldn't be very portable. :-/

Comment: On the contrary, but it will be bigger than needed. Anyway, try to look for `libbfd*.so` and `libopcodes*.so` in your distribution, If you do not find it, it means that this is the problem. I know that the Debian (unstable) package of the binutils-dev has the `.so` files, but it is not the case in many distributions.

Comment: I have the .so for both libraries though. I don't think it is portable, because in my case they live in /usr/lib64; however, someone could compile binutils from source and then the files would live in /usr/local/lib.

Comment: So, the solution is easy. You can fix your problem by having this line of compilation: `gcc ./main.c -lbfd -liberty -lz -ldl -lopcodes -g -o bfd_se -L/usr/lib64`. And, now that I think about it, you might also need to get the multiarch package (it seems to be stuck at ARM architectures).

Comment: Hmm...this seems to be part of a bigger problem dealing with linking. I'll accept this answer, but I'll post another question very shortly.

Comment: In fact, I know exactly your problem because I had it as well. So far, I did not find a good solution to get rid of it. So, I totally understand that my answer do not satisfy you. I won't blame you for that, believe me. :-)

Comment: Well, I'm on the standalone program, I can use libopcodes; however, when integrating it into a larger project, it'll make the .o file, but fails when linking everything to main..

Comment: Correct solution (for part of my program) is to use foo_LDADD instead of foo_LDFLAGS. The libraries need to come after instead of before when clobbering all the object files together.